# Determine domain name registered in a name server

Tags: ip-address

Suppose I have a new nameserver that is set up to associate my domain name with the IP address of my new web server (but isn't a nameserver for my domain name yet). My domain name is still using with my old nameserver which provides the IP of my old web server.

How can I test that my new name server will redirect to the correct IP address before I switch my domain to using the new name server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand it, a "DNS Server" and a web hosting "Name Server" are fundamentally the same thing, you should just be able to manually set your computer's DNS to use the new nameserver ip ([like as shown here for Win 7](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows7/Change-TCP-IP-settings)). Then, open cmd prompt, enter

```
ipconfig /dnsflush
```

to clear your dns cache and your new nameserver should be the computers sole DNS server. If the site wont load, ping should tell you what IP its directing to or if its not responding to that domain name request.

Comment: Just wanted to add some notes for Mac. [Configuring DNS](http://macs.about.com/od/networking/qt/configure-your-macs-dns.htm) and [Flushing the DNS](http://support.apple.com/en-au/HT202516)